# Neo4j alternative to HTTP

Tags: neo4j

I'm looking for the most efficient and 'persistent' connection method from my application server to my Neo4j instance. Both are running on the same machine. The application server is made with node.js

I'm talking:

```
Persistent TCP connection (not counting HTTP w/ Connection: keep-alive)
Unix sockets
Shared memory?
```

The Neo4j docs are all about the HTTP method, can't seem to find much about any other way?

I've found this third party method:
https://github.com/joewhite86/node-neo4j-embedded
but the large bug warning in the readme and beta only support for Neo4j 2.0+ are severely discouraging

http://www.neo4j.org/tracks/neo4j_server says: "It has an interactive and friendly Web-Interface and a fast, transactional HTTP-Endpoint for Cypher. Most of the drivers support the Neo4j server."

I'm not even sure what the second sentence of that means.

Comment: What language is your application using? Is there any particular reason to use a network connection between it and Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there's no native binary protocol option for Neo4J, the only options you have are:

- REST HTTP API
- A ["transactional HTTP endpoint for cypher 2.0"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/_ggHNyWWnJ4/5LROgpOupgoJ)
- Use [Neo4J embedded](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html)

There are some wrappers for these things - [in Java for both](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding), in almost [any language for the REST](http://neo4j.com/contrib/) option.

There was a topic on the official Google Group about this, and [apparently a binary protocol was in plan](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/_ggHNyWWnJ4/GCd_ALF03PAJ). Then [plans have changed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/_ggHNyWWnJ4/5LROgpOupgoJ) probably.

Anyway on the [Spring Data Neo4J](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/reference_neo4j-server.html) documentation page it states:

> Future versions of Spring Data Neo4j will use the more performant batch API as well as a binary protocol.

So probably they're still working on it.

Alternatively I was thinking it would be possible to use the [RexPro binary protocol](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/RexPro), using [Neo4J + Rexster](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations). I'm not sure the effort is worth but you could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Marco, very useful answer. You're right the plans seem to have changed, the google groups conversation is quite dated. From the neo4j Spring Data: "Please also keep in mind that performing graph operations via the REST-API is about one order of magnitude slower than local operations" -- I guess we're stuck with the "World's Leading Graph Database‎", performing queries at 1/10th efficiency. For now.

Answer (score 0):

As of neo4j 3.0.0+ there is a new way to communicate with neo4j. Its called BOLT. More information about it: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-milestone-1-release/

Drivers are available here:

http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/